# How to import multiple products with variants in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to import a CSV in Magento that contains multiple variants of products. How to do that? I'm stuck please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which Magento version you're using. Probably this can help you
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-transfer-configurable-products.html

Comment: I'm using the Magento version.2.3.0

Comment: Then follow this guide https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/system/data-transfer-configurable-products.html